# Why do the bubbles in a champagne accelerate?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, kinematics, bubbles

The bubbles in champagne are familiar to most people. They form almost exclusively at the specific points in the champagne glass, and from these they rise faster and faster. Why *do* the bubbles in champagne accelerate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the other answers point out, the force that accelerates the bubble is buoyancy counteracted by drag and the weight of the bubble. The process that leads to perceptible acceleration of the bubble all the way while it rises, however, is that the bubble grows as gas diffuses into it, which increases the terminal velocity.

To show this, let's first solve the problem for a bubble of constant size.

### Velocity of a Bubble of Constant Size

The drag for a small sphere at low Reynolds numbers is the Stokes drag $$ F_D = -6\pi \eta r v. $$
The net buoyancy (buoyancy plus the weight of the bubble) is given by
$$ F_B = \frac 4 3 \pi r^3 (\rho_l - \rho_g) g. $$
The mass of the bubble is
$$ m = \frac 4 3 \pi r^3 \rho_g. $$

The equation governing the dynamics of a bubble of constant diameter is:
$$ m\dot v = F_D + F_B $$

The solution to that equation, with the initial condition $v(0) = v_0$, is
$$ v(t) = v_\infty + (v_0 - v_\infty) e^{-t/\tau}, $$
with the time constant $\tau$
$$ \tau = \frac{2 r^2 \rho_g}{9 \eta} $$
and the terminal velocity $v_\infty$
$$ v_\infty = \frac{2 r^2 (\rho_l - \rho_g) g}{9 \eta}. $$

Of course this is just an approximation, as a bubble rising in water is not exactly spherical, etc. But it is a sufficient approximation.

Using the viscosity of water and the density of Carbon dioxide at 10 °C we can estimate time constant $\tau$ for a bubble 2 mm in diameter:
$$ \rho_g = 2\,\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^3}} $$
$$ \eta = 1.3\,\mathrm{mPa \cdot s} $$
$$ \tau \approx 0.3\,\mathrm{ms} $$

(Yes I know that viscosity of champagne is different from the one of water, but just need the order of magnitude here. Which is *milliseconds*.)

This means that the terminal velocity would be reached within a few milliseconds for a 2 mm diameter bubble and much faster for smaller ones, and in turn, that the acceleration you see is not caused by the bubble reaching its terminal velocity over the height of the glass.

### What happens for a real bubble in champagne

So the conclusion is that the acceleration you see is because the bubble does not have a constant radius! (Which you can easily observe.)

The effect of the change of hydrostatic pressure is minute, the atmospheric pressure corresponds to about 10 m of water column, so the relative change in hydrostatic pressure, as the bubble rises in a glass (with a water column of perhaps 10 cm) is only 1%.

The relevant process is that gas is diffusing from the champagne to the bubble. There is a net diffusion into the bubble, because champagne is an over-saturated solution of carbon dioxide. The rate of diffusion approximately proportional to the surface area of the bubble, thereby we have $r \propto t$ for the bubble radius $r$. This increased bubble size means an increased terminal velocity and the bubble accelerates to match that. Since the time constant for reaching the terminal velocity is so small, we can say, as a not too bad estimate, that
$$ v(t) = v_\infty(r(t)) \propto r(t)^2 \propto t^2. $$

And this matches the observation of the bubble accelerating more and more as it rises.

Comment: A relevant source: https://doi.org/10.2113/GSELEMENTS.4.1.47

If you have any other sources as well that would be great

Comment: Approach is interesting, however you missed the bubble weight, which altogether with drag force opposes buoyancy , so complete dynamics equation should be $m\dot v = W+F_D + F_B$. You can't neglect gravity.

Comment: Gravity is in Sebastian's expression for $F_B$, the $V\rho_g g$ term.

Sebastian, I think you typo'd $\rho_f$ instead of $\rho_l$ in the equation for terminal velocity. (Or vice-versa with the earlier bouyancy force equation.)

Comment: Yup you are right – I'll fix the typo and clarify that $F_B$ is the net force due to buoyancy and gravity acting on the bubble.

Comment: Also, you can pretty much neglect the weight of the bubble, since the density of carbon dioxide gas is about $0.2\%$ of the density of water, so the weight it is just a minute correction to the buoyancy.

Answer (score 1):

Basic forces which compete are buoyancy force and body weight. From here we can write net force equation :
$$ ma = mg - \rho_{_f} gV $$
where $\rho_{_f}$ is fluid density, $V$ - body volume, or body's expelled liquid volume to be correct.

Solving equation above for body acceleration, gives :
$$ a = g\left(1-\frac{\rho_{_f}}{\rho_{_b}}\right) $$
where $\rho_{_b}$ body density.

When $\rho_{_f} \lt\rho_{_b}$, then body goes down with positive acceleration and when $\rho_{_f} \gt \rho_{_b}$ - then body goes up with negative acceleration. $\rho_{_f} = \rho_{_b}$ - body stays at rest. In your case bubbles are filled with $\text{CO}_2$ gases which has relatively low density compared to champagne fluid. So in the parenthesized expression we get something $\lt 0$ and thus negative acceleration with which bubbles goes up.

It's worth to mention that this acceleration is not ever-lasting, because actually there's drag force too which comes into play at high speeds (fluid resistance to movement). So due to drag force at some point in time body should reach terminal speed, over which it can't speed-up anymore because any speedup will be canceled by equivalent increase of drag force. Does CO2 bubbles are able to reach terminal speed until they catches fluid surface - is another question out of scope here.

Comment: This neglects the dynamics of the diameter of the gas bubble, which are very important here.

Comment: I don't think so. Increase of gas bubble (absorption of more gases) will just amplify acceleration effect which was caused by **buoyancy force**. If not the drive of buoyancy force, your mentioned dynamics would change nothing. So this dynamics would just add corrected term on bubble acceleration, but nothing would change in principle. Removing buoyancy - would change. Your priorities are incorrect.

Comment: Certainly the buoyancy is the force that drives the acceleration, but without the bubble growing, it will, as you describe, asymptotically reach a maximum velocity instead of continuing to accelerate. The time constant of that process is incredibly short, my back-of-the envelope estimation says it is on the scale a millisecond! So you wouldn't really see the bubble accelerate as it would reach terminal velocity very quickly! You see the acceleration, because the bubble is growing (and thereby increasing its terminal velocity ${} \propto r^2$)!

Comment: I somehow doubt that due to the increase of bubble size, acceleration should increase. And oh, seems you missed that bubble density does include it's diameter, bc $$\rho_b = \frac {m}{\pi/6\ d^3}$$. So when bubble grows, CO2 accumulated mass in the bubble also grows, thus bubble density must stay the same. And btw, increase of bubble cross-section, must also increase opposing drag force, which is $F_{D}\,=\,{\tfrac {1}{2}}\,\rho \,v^{2}\,C_{D}\,A$. So I doubt your conclusion about terminal velocity increase due to bubble size change.

Comment: The density of the gas stays the same as the pressure stays the same (modulo surface tension, but that only increases the effect of growing radius with growing particle number, as the pressure due to surface tension goes like $1/r$). Also in the regime we are talking about the correct equation for the drag is Stokes drag $\propto v r$ (see my answer), not the turbulent drag $\propto v^2 r^2$ you propose. Note that even for turbulent drag you still have an increase of the terminal velocity in dependency of the bubble size $\propto \sqrt{r}$.

Answer (score 1):

A constant buoyancy force on a bubble will accelerate it to some extent, but as it speeds up the drag force from the liquid increases, and the bubble will quickly reach an equilibrium speed at which the buoyancy force and drag force are equal. However, there is another factor at play here.

As a bubble rises the pressure in the surrounding liquid decreases, so the bubble expands. A larger bubble displaces a greater mass of liquid so the buoyancy force on it increases. A greater buoyancy force increases the equilibrium speed of the bubble, so it goes faster as it rises.

The effect can be seen in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GrLCbpGySI) - if you look at the chains of small bubbles you will see the bubbles become larger *and* more spaced out as they rise.

Comment: More important than the falling pressure is that more gas diffuses from the solution into the gas bubble with time, which causes the bubble to expand. Note that the relative pressure change in a glass is minute.

Answer (score -2):

A bubble rises because there is lower pressure (in this case champagne pressure) above the bubble than below it.  As the bubble gets higher, the pressure continues to decrease and this allows for the acceleration.  This is exactly the same as with a cork that has been pulled underwater.

What is interesting in this physics forum is that this is completely analogous to the way that gravity causes an object to fall with increasing acceleration.  In fact, a race of people living beneath the sea would say that a rock experiences gravity and a cork experiences antigravity.  Both behave in exactly the same manner.  I theorize that this is because gravity is actually a low pressure system in spacetime.
[image: Rock and cork]

Comment: Pressure decreases above AND below the bubble, so overall buoyancy effect does not depend on exact depth, but rather on pressure difference between above and below object, which stays $\text {const}$ as object rises. Both rock and cork experiences gravity and buoyancy, simply net force will be different for them. In physics no such thing as "antigravity", unless you have a negative mass. Lastly sorry, but personal theories are not supported in this forum.

Comment: That pressure difference above and below the bubble is everything.  If you look at a bubble in water in space, you see that it doesn't rise, but remains in the middle of the water.  https://www.usgs.gov/special-topic/water-science-school/science/water-space-how-does-water-behave-outer-space?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas Yes, pressure decreases above and below, but the pressure above will always be less than that below, so the bubble is essentially chasing itself upwards.  Regarding "antigravity", I was using that as a simple example.  I'm trying to explain gravity as a pressure system, because I've learned that it acts exactly in that way.  So far nobody has supplied a better explanation.

Comment: Seems you don't understood my critics. I'm citing you "_As the bubble gets higher, the pressure continues to decrease and this allows for the acceleration_". **Wrong**. Acceleration is NOT caused by decreasing pressure with decreasing depth of bubble. Acceleration is given by buoyancy, which in turn is due to pressure **difference** between low and high immersed object parts. Acceleration due to buoyancy is indifferent to decreasing pressure with decreasing height, in contrary what you have said.

Comment: As about your "gravity explanation" - it's already explained by Newton and Einstein. Unless you have full scale quantum gravity theory in your mind. If you do - you can publish it in any scientific journal, you are welcome.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas  this is not the place for an extended discussion so I won't pursue it any further.  And yes, I do have a "full scale quantum gravity theory" based on gluon field excitation.  And I'm working to get it published.  Let me know if you'd like to help.

Comment: Gluons binds quarks in a nucleons- such as proton and neutron, so gluons has relation with strong nuclear interaction, but has nothing to do with gravity at all. Do not mess-up different kinds of forces. Besides if you would be introduced to gravitational lensing, you would know that photon trajectory can be bended by massive stars gravitation. So something transmits gravity to photon too in quantum mechanical terms. However photon has nothing to do with gluons at all, because it's just quanta of electromagnetic wave. Lastly do not invent bicycle, better check info about graviton.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas  This is far outside the scope of this OP.   Look at my answer to this question to see a link to the paper.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/669093/can-we-think-of-space-as-any-kind-of-aether-in-any-way/669100#669100   Then feel free to contact me directly.